# excel 2012 Getting error message on paste after the data is pasted

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm getting a Run-Time error '1004'
"Paste method of Worksheet class failed"
After the paste was completed.
if I enter press Debug and move the pointer to the next line of the macro everything works fine,(until the loop comes back to the paste line"
This is the code block:

```
    Set r1 = Range(Cells(2, col1), Cells(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, col6))
    Set r2 = Range(Cells(2, col7), Cells(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, col9))
    Union(r1, r2).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

After I've bypassed the line, to get past the error, for as many iterations as the loop requires, the macro completes, the sheet looks fine and contains no error.

If I manually perform the cut-and-paste, I get no errors.

I've run out of ideas.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: No errors here. As with all example code, it is best to provide all variable values so that others can reproduce your error. for instance is `col9` a variable in your code? Is is set somewhere? It might have something to do with another open object/workbook or something in the clipboard.

Comment: A good start would be to [avoid Select](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/445425)